# How can I open a man page in a new terminal window?

Tags: command-line, command, man

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with a workflow issue. I sometimes open up a man page for a command, take note of several command options and parameters, go back to the command line and then input that command with the options I just looked up.

**Is there someway that I can open up a man page in a new terminal window so that I don't have to rely on my memory or copy and paste relevant info into a text editor? Is there an alternative workflow that will solve my issue?**

Thanks so much.

Comment: That's what I use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) for.

Comment: Oooh that looks like it will make my life better for sure.

Comment: you can try [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) as well. There're quite a few other alternatives. Google'em.

Comment: Thanks cychoi. Now that I know to search for "multiplex" I'm all good.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
xterm -e 'man xeyes'&
```

Which will open a new xterm window and run the command 'man xeyes' in it.

Comment: I would also add: Add `&;` to background the `xterm` process in order to bring up a new prompt in the current shell.

Comment: I updated my answer with '&' at the end. Thanks @jayhendren

Answer (score 2):

In case that you just want to try out the command, you don't need to open a new terminal window.

If you pipe `man` output through a pager (e.g.: `less` or `more`), you can always hit the bang character (`!`) followed by the command and options to execute the command.

If you need a new shell to review the command output, you can try screen multiplexers such as [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), [Byobu](http://byobu.co/), etc, in which you can [split windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Regions.html#Regions), [create windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Screen-Command.html#Screen-Command), [switch windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Selecting.html#Selecting), [persist processes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Detach.html#Detach), [view independent scrollback buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Copy.html#Copy) and [more](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/index.html).

If you are in a GUI environment, most terminal emulators support [tabbed document interface (TDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)) such that you can open multiple shells / terminal windows in a terminal emulator window for easy switching.

Comment: I wasn't aware you can use `!` to input commands while using `less` and `more`. That's a super helpful tip - thanks!

Comment: Noted that `!` (shell commands) and `/` / `?` (search commands) for `less` has their own histories such that you can use up / down arrow keys to navigate the histories once you pressed the special keys.